# Page not found page not mobile friendly

Tags: bug, mobile

Earlier I had deleted a question that I asked which had generated no activity. I did this while browsing the mobile site. When I clicked 'delete' I got a popup to confirm and was then redirected to a 'page not found' because the question had been deleted, by me.

However, this page was not formatted for mobile so I thought I'd raise this in case it's a bug.

Comment: Probably belongs on Meta.SO, because this kind of thing can't possibly be specific to AD only. Would you like me to migrate it?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Would you like me to migrate this to the main meta for the network? I presume this isn't something specific to our site - but will poke at the issue a bit in case it is.

Comment: @bmike Network, not site. Don't get up, I already made the change :).

Comment: We're keeping bugs here as the site developers have said there's no need to move things to meta. Also, can anyone tell if this is really a bug or just that the landing page after deletion wasn't styled in mobile?